# How do I rewrite my URLS with .htaccess and mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have my URLS in this format:

http://www.domain.com/game.php?id=3434&title=title-goes-here

I would like the URLs to be written as:

http://www.domain.com/ID/title-goes-here.html

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create an .htaccess file in the root of your website and put this in it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /game.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```